# Magento 2: Problem in rounding the price of a bundle product

Tags: magento2, bundle-product, rounding, tax-rounding

I am not an expert in Magento and I have a problem with the sum of my bundle product when it shows the final price.
[image: Product Issue]

The total sum of the product should be 4,850.00 but as we see it shows 4,849.99 and it should not be like that, if I inspect the code of my browser I see that the data-price-amount is 4850 and it should be the same as what is printed on the span tag with class "price".

[image: Chrome]

The closest thing I can find where this value is printed is in the following paths that are from my theme /app/code/Smartwave/Dailydeals/view/frontend/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml & /app /design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml

[image: Code]

Where the $deal_final_price_amount is the final calculated price and the first time it is calculated with the data-price-amount it comes out correct at 4850 closed, but in the price span it comes out with decimals.

Note: the total sum of my products with the tax configuration in "total" gives 4849.993903 but for this reason I have the tax configuration in "Unit Price" so that it adds up to 4850.